# Difference in List

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to write a function which gives difference between lists.
For example,

```
list1 = ['a','a','a','b','c','d','d']
list2 = ['a','a','a','b','c','a','d']
list = diff(list1, list2)
print(list)
```

list should be `['d','a']`, the elements which don't match in both.
I thought of using set but it won't work as it'll eliminate repeating characters.

Comment: give a more clear explanation: why it should be `['d']`, but not `['a']` or  `['d', 'a']`?

Comment: yes, I edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I both lists have the same length, you can use `zip`:

```
res = []
for x, y in zip(list1, list2):
    if x != y:
        res.extend((x, y))
print(res)
```

Output:

```
['d', 'a']
```

Or as one-liner:

```
>>> [z for x, y in zip(list1, list2) if x != y for z in (x, y)]
['d', 'a']
```

If both lists have different lengths and you want this counted as a difference, you can use `zip_longest`:

```
from itertools import zip_longest

list1 = ['a','a','a','b','c','d','d', 'x']
list2 = ['a','a','a','b','c','a','d']

res = []

for x, y in zip_longest(list1, list2):
    if x != y:
        res.extend((x, y))
print(res)
```

Output:

```
['d', 'a', 'x', None]
```

Again as one-liner

```
>>> [z for x, y in zip_longest(list1, list2) if x != y for z in (x, y)]
['d', 'a', 'x', None]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming same length of both lists

```
def diff(l,m):
ans = []
for i in range(len(l)):  
   if l[i]!=m[i]:
      ans.append(l[i])
      ans.append(m[i])
return ans
```

What I have done in the code is that I am iterating over each element of the lists and checking them for equality. If they are same then nothing happens, loop goes to its next iteration and if they are not same both the elements are appended to the `ans` list.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a one-line `list-comprehension`:

```
[e for i, j in zip(list1, list2) if i != j for e in (i, j)]
```

which gives:

```
['d', 'a']
```

---

**why?**

Well first we need to understand what the `zip()` function does, and this can be seen through an example:

```
>>> list(zip([1,2], [3,4]))
[(1, 3), (2, 4)]
```

as you can see, it simply "zips" the two `lists` together (*note that `zip` works on any `iterable`, not just `lists`*).

We then want to iterate through each of these `tuples` and *unpack* them so that we can work with both elements.

Next, we check whether the two elements are *not* the same with `i != j`. This means that we are now only working with variables `i` an `j` if they are *different*.

Finally, as your expected output wants a *flattened* list, we need to use another `loop` to add `i` and `j` as separate elements to out whole `list` that we are creating.

---

*Note that this relies on the two lists being the same length as `zip()` stops at the end of the shortest one.*

Comment: Looks just like my alternative answer.

Comment: @MikeMüller I didn't copy if that's what you were suggesting, I agree I posted mine `2` mins later, but I was testing it and writing it throughout!

Answer (score 0):

Filtering pairwise with `itertools` and `zip()` function:

```
import itertools

list1 = ['a','a','a','b','c','d','d']
list2 = ['a','a','a','b','c','a','d']
result = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(
    itertools.filterfalse(lambda x: x[0] == x[1], zip(list1, list2))))

print(result)
```

The output:

```
['d', 'a']
```